# Control Tab - Blue Prism RPA

Tags: blueprism

Is there anyone who knows how to get the environment information of an available process from the Control tab? I would like to retrieve the user's name and the start time. I attach a screenshot to better illustrate my question.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What would you like to retrieve again?

Answer (score 1):

In your process make a data item and set Exposure to Session. Fill this Data Item with username by using a calculation step that moves your Environmental value into the newly created Data Item. You can also do the same for start time, but would just use the start time you can already see in your screen shot, if it was me :)

Go to Control room and launch your process and when the step you made in your process is done, you will have the data in control room by clicking 'Session Management' -> Show Session Variables.

If you want to see the values before running, then it's a question of where you pass user name to the robot. This can be in schedules or Env Variables.